# Hardening network infrastrucure?

Tags: hardening

I would like to know, what are the best hardening methodologies, procedures, and books to use when hardening your network? Especially for the following:

- Windows /Linux Server
- SQL server
- Microsoft Information Services (IIS)

Comment: Hi Ali, this is actually several different questions. Some of them have already been answered, you can search through the `[hardening]` tag. Please split them out to individual questions, and add some more detail on your context, risk profile, etc - See the [FAQ] and [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit vague, however I have used a VM called Network Security Toolkit (NST) that you can read abou and download from here: http://networksecuritytoolkit.org/nst/index.html
NST does a lot so I reccomend loading up a virtual machine and play, er I mean test it out and see how much of your concerns that it could cover. :-)

With your SQL DB and application is it explosed to the web, if so then how. What logging measures and precautions are currently being taken? Is the application wide open to be accessed from any IP? Do you want to limit specific Geographic traffic? Encryption being used in any way on the network, if so how?

Have you been able to identify what kind of attacks are coming from where? If so what are they?

Answer (score 1):

You could look at the [Center for Internet Security](http://www.cisecurity.org/).  They have some pretty comprehensive hardening documents which cover a decent range of technologies